# Calling a function isn't working

Tags: c, function

I've googled a bit but I haven't found any answers to my question. 
What I'm trying to do, is to call my function inside another function.
**I have shorten down my code a bit so its not too long for you to read.**
This is how my code looks:

```
void hearts(struct Card *cardDeck);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
    void hearts(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }
        printf("of hearts");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void randomize() {
    int random_card;
    random_card = card() % 4 + 1;

    if (random_card == 1) {
        hearts(); //It gives me an error here, why?
    }

}
```

So basically, I can't call hearts(), I mean, visual studio gives me an error that I've called too few arguments, which I don't understand.
Would love some guidance here.

Comment: You need to give `hearts` a pointer to a deck of cards.

Comment: 1) Use correct prototype declarators. C is not C++. `void f()` means not the same in both languages! 2) you do not call any function in `main`.

Comment: `int main()
{
    return 0;
}
  ` ????

Comment: @Olaf In a function definition, `void f()` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Please read the C standard. old-style declartors are obsolescense; I did not say it is wrong syntax (still hoping the future direction in the standard means it will eventually). And It definitively means something different in C and C++. Please elaborate where my comment is **wrong**. But for `main` it is not standard compliant - presuming a hosted environment, of course.

Comment: @Olaf `void f()` and `void f(void)` only have a different meaning in declarations, in function definitions, both denote a function taking no arguments, cf. ISO 9899:2011 §6.7.6.4 ¶14.

Comment: Just do yourself a favour and use a Windows-compiler *only* to create windows programs. For other C stuff use a C compiler.

Comment: @FUZxxl: 1) There is no 6.7.6.4, at least in n1570. You mean 6.7.6.3? Interesting. I was not aware about that asymmetry.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah sorry, §6.7.6.3 was meant.

Answer (score 2):

See , how you declared hearts .

```
void hearts(struct Card *cardDeck)
```

It means it will take a pointer to struct card .
You are calling without any argument .

```
if (random_card == 1) {
        hearts(); //calling without any argument .
    }
```

So, solution would be create a pointer to struct card and

```
if (random_card == 1) {
           struct Card c1;
            hearts(&c1); //passing the address of struct card 
        }
```

Comment: Oh i see, thank you!
So when i call the function randomize() in main, is it going to take any arguments or how do i call it?

Comment: Because when im calling randomize() it gives me an error, but if i change the function to int randomize() and call it, i get some trash number like -823213 of hearts... 

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: @phil_sw: you can directly call randomize() without any argument as long as you don't want to perform any operation on struct card .

Comment: Well when i call randomize() in main it gives me an error.

Comment: @phil_sw: if return type of function is void , you should not try to store the return value else it will give error . if you are trying to store return , mention the correct return type accordingly .

Comment: @phil_sw: show me , how are you calling randomize() from main .I am sure you are trying to store its return value.

Answer (score -2):

You created the void `hearts();` with a `struct`, and when calling it, you're not adding that argument that you put in, Therefore your Compiler will throw out errors.
You need to give it a pointer, for the cards.

Comment: `void hearts();` is a declarator.and it uses ancient incomplete syntax. The rest of your answer is not clear.

Comment: I've been doing too much C++. I already know the structure of voids, anyway.

Comment: Actually, with this declaration of `hearts`, you can call it with any number of arguments of any type(s).